# On Ramanujan's proof of Bertrand's postulate (using stirling formula)

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

I'm trying to understand Ramanujan's [proof](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram24.pdf) of Bertrand's postulate, but I don't get the step in which it says

> But is easy to see that
>
> $\log\Gamma(x) - 2\log\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}) \le \log[x]! - 2\log[\frac{1}{2}x]! \le \log\Gamma(x+1) - 2\log\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2})$
>
> Then, applying Stirling's approximation, Ramanujan gets to:
>
> $\log[x]! - 2\log[\frac{1}{2}x]! < \frac{3}{4}x$ if $x > 0$
>
> and
>
> $\log[x]! - 2\log[\frac{1}{2}x]! > \frac{2}{3}x$ if $x > 300$

How does he use Stirling formula to get those inequalities?

I know this have been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342520/stirlings-approximation-and-ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate?rq=1), but I'm trying to find another explanation because I'm not familiar with the method used by the user who answered.

I hope someone can help me understand.

Comment: I think you can do it with just the error estimate of Stirling $$0\leq\log\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\sqrt{2\pi x}(x/e)^x}\leq\frac1{12x}$$ for all $x>0$